# Selenium Safari WebDriver crashes immediately

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, safari, bots

When trying to run `.get()`, the automated safari window opens and tries to load the given URL, but crashes immediately with "Safari has crashed unexpectedly" window.

The snippet just the beginning of a fully functional bot I made a few months ago. When coming back and trying to run it again, I have encountered this error.

My safari does have the "allow remote automation" option checked.

The WebDriver test code provided in the documentation causes the same issue, where the automation window opens then crashes safari immediately. I am on the latest versions of safari and MacOS.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self, username, pw):
        self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
        self.username = username
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
```

Code opens automated safari window with instagram.com in the URL box, then crashes safari immediately.

Regarding browser/driver compatibility, latest versions installed, according to WebDriver Safari has native support, are there any recent compatibility issues? I have not found anything online.

Safari version 15.6, Selenium version 4.3.0, Python 3.10.5.

Comment: Check the browser/driver compatibility and update the question.